# Visual Basics and Emojis =3D graphics

Tags: vba

Using Visual Basic and Emojis , symbols will coding with emojis an symbols using a ICon for basic words ever be a reality?

Ex: My name is  D3&@ &  ☸️️

I AM AN ,,the .

Answer (score 2):

The VBA Editor itself does not support displaying Unicode. If you paste an emoji in you will get `??` in the editor.

VBA however *does* support manipulating Unicode using `ChrW()` and `AscW()`

`ChrW()` converts a Unicode character code in `Long` format into a Unicode string.
You can find a list of all the character codes for emojis here.
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji.asp
use the "Dec" column.

`AscW()` converts a Unicode character into a character code.

```
Sub WriteUnicode()
    Dim UnicodeCode As Long
    UnicodeCode = 8986  '8986 is the code for the watch emoji
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = ChrW(UnicodeCode)
End Sub
```

[A watch emoji written into the spreasheet by the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZJXK.png)